# Quero colocar uma musica de fundo em meu projeto C#

Tags: c#

Galera, este é o código que criei, mas quando eu aperto o botão, o form simplesmente trava e nada mais funciona, eu só consigo fechá-lo pelo Gerenciador de tarefas, mas no projeto nenhum erro é mostrado...

```
 public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                _SoundPlayer = new SoundPlayer("music1.wav");
            }

            private void dualStateButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (dualStateButton.Checked)
                {
                    dualStateButton.Text = "Stop";
                    _SoundPlayer.Play();

                }
                else
                {
                    dualStateButton.Text = "Play";
                    _SoundPlayer.Stop();
                }
```

Comment: Já verificou o caminho do arquivo .wav ?

Comment: Coloca um try catch nos métodos para tentar capturar o erro.

Comment: Não existe nada de errado com o código apresentado, desde que o arquivo tenha sido incluído no projeto e esteja sendo copiado junto à compilação. Mas caso não estiver seria apresentado o erro de que não foi encontrado.

O que pode estar acontecendo no seu caso é o arquivo ser muito grande e o travamento da UI se dá pelo tempo de carregamento do arquivo na memória